# NpgsqlConnection fails when database has been dropped and recreated

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

For an XUnit integration test automation project, that runs with a PostgreSQL database, I have created a script that first drops and then recreates the database, so that every test can start with the same set of data as input. When I run the tests individually (one-by-one) through the test explorer, they all run fine. When I try to run them all in the same testrun it fails on the second test that is being executed

The structure of every test is:

- initialize the new database using the script that drops, creates and fills it with data
- run the test
- open a NpgsqlConnection to the database
- query the database and check if the resulting content matches my expectations

the second time this causes a Npgsql.NpgsqlException : Exception while writing to stream

it seems that when the connection is being created for the second time, NpgSql sees it's a previously used connection, so it reuses it. But it has been dropped and can't be used again.
If for instance I don't use the command query after creating the first connection and only in the second connection it also works fine.
I hope someone can give me a good suggestion on how to deal with this. It is the first time that I use PostgreSQL in one of my projects. I could maybe use the entity framework data provider for PostgreSQL but I will try asking this first...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added Pooling=false to the connection string and now it works. I can drop and recreate the database as often as I want now in the same test, and simply reconnect to it from the C# code

[image]

Comment: That's probably a good solution - the point of pooling is to reuse connections, but if you're dropping the database in the meantime they would obviously become broken.

Comment: However, note that creating and dropping database for each *test* is quite a heavy-handed approach that would likely result in slow test performance... Read-only tests can run the same database without any further modifications, and there are other techniques for tests which write (e.g. run in a transaction, roll back at the end). Or reset/truncate all data at the end.

Comment: I understand that perfectly well, The database is however quite small, so it is not a problem.

Comment: The size of your database had little to do with it. The slowdown comes from continuously dropping and creating databases, as well as from continuously created new physical connections (i.e. not using pooling).